# Why can't I access my Espresso framework application?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the [Espresso framework](https://github.com/slivu/espresso), but I'm having problems in the "hello world" example.

I've implemented this code:

```
require 'e'

class App < E

  def hello
    "Hello World!"
  end

end

App.run
```

When I run the command `ruby hello.rb`, I get this:

```
[2012-08-15 20:54:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-08-15 20:54:55] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
[2012-08-15 20:54:55] WARN  TCPServer Error: Normalmente é permitida apenas uma utilização de cada endereço de soquete (protocolo/endereço de rede/porta). - bind(2)
[2012-08-15 20:54:55] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6460 port=80
```

It seems it is booting up properly but when I try to acess the URL `localhost:80/hello`, it just doesn't work. I get a "Not Found: /hello", and in the console the output is:

```
[15/Aug/2012:20:56:47] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 17
- -> /hello
```

Can anybody tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: What about routing, how the framework know to which action it should redirect?

Comment: I think it knows by the acessed url /hello would match to def hello action which should print hello... but it doenst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im pretty sure it should be:

```
require 'e'

class App < E

  map '/' #important

  def hello
    "Hello World!"
  end

end

App.run
```

Comment: This is correct. If the `map` statement is not present, the base URL would be `/app` and hence, you should check `/app/hello`

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked! it was really missing the map '/'. thanks, cheers